# PHP get_file_contents with FTP server file

Tags: php, ftp, file-get-contents

I making something and i need a bit of help. 
First i using FTP informations to connect to server and get some file something like this:

```
$ftp_ip = $info['ftp_ip'];
$ftp_user = $info['ftp_user'];
$ftp_password = $info['ftp_password'];

$filename = "ftp://$ftp_user:$ftp_password@$ftp_ip/cstrike/addons/amxmodx/configs/serverlist.ini";  

$file_headers = file_get_contents($filename);
if($file_headers == ""){
 echo " error ";        
} else {

$lines = file($filename);

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
   if (!preg_match("/^(\;|\s)/",$line)) echo nl2br($line);      
}

}
```

The file 'serverlist.ini' looks like this :

```
; Menu configuration file
; File location: $moddir/addons/amxmodx/configs/configs.ini
; To use with Commands Menu plugin

; NOTE: By default in all settings the access level is set to "u".
;       However you can change that, to limit the access to some settings.

; Commands Menu:
; < description > < command > < flags > < access level >
; "a" - execute from server console
; "b" - execute from admin console
; "c" - execute on all clients
; "d" - back to menu when executed

[Extreme ProGaming Fun]
address=77.105.36.100
port=27028
noauto=0
nodisplay=0


[Extreme ProGaming Knife]
address=77.105.36.102
port=27010
noauto=0
nodisplay=0


[Extreme ProGaming DeatMatch]
address=77.105.36.103
port=27026
noauto=0
nodisplay=0
```

With this PHP code bellow i get something like this:

```
[Extreme ProGaming Fun]
address=77.105.36.100
port=27028
noauto=0
nodisplay=0
[Extreme ProGaming Knife]
address=77.105.36.102
port=27010
noauto=0
nodisplay=0
[Extreme ProGaming DeatMatch]
address=77.105.36.103
port=27026
noauto=0
nodisplay=0
```

And now i need to get on other file just to get something like this from this serverlist.ini via get_file_contents :
From serverlist.ini file to get just address and port in format adress:port

```
1. 77.105.36.100:27028  // Extreme ProGaming Fun
2. 77.105.36.102:27010  // Extreme ProGaming Knife
3. 77.105.36.103:27026  // Extreme ProGaming DeatMatch
```

Sorry for my bad english i think u guys understand what i need :)

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that this path actually exists:

`ftp://$ftp_user:$ftp_password@$ftp_ip/cstrike/addons/amxmodx/configs/serverlist.ini`

Meaning if you login to FTP and navigate to `/cstrike/addons/amxmodx/configs/`, you will see the `serverlist.ini` file.

If you are able to get the file, the next thing you need to do is parse the INI file. This can be achieved via `parse_ini_string()`

Example:

```
$ftp_ip = $info['ftp_ip'];
$ftp_user = $info['ftp_user'];
$ftp_password = $info['ftp_password'];

$filename = "ftp://$ftp_user:$ftp_password@$ftp_ip/cstrike/addons/amxmodx/configs/serverlist.ini";  

$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
if(false === $contents){
 echo " error ";        
} else {
    $ini = parse_ini_string($contents, true); // use true in second parameter to indicate this INI has blocks
    $i = 1;
    foreach($ini as $server => $config) {
        echo "$i. {$config['address']}:{$config['port']} // $server\n";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Which will yield:

```
1. 77.105.36.100:27028 // Extreme ProGaming Fun
2. 77.105.36.102:27010 // Extreme ProGaming Knife
3. 77.105.36.103:27026 // Extreme ProGaming DeatMatch
```

See full example/test here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/K2hB46

Comment: I have problems with this code when i try to use while here: this is a full code of all http://pastebin.com/ajSrMuBU any example how to solve this?